# How to resolve alias in Parceljs?

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I'm migrating from Webpack to Parcel and I use folder aliases like this in my component:

```
import * as authActions from 'actions/authActions';
```

I get this error: `Cannot find module 'actions/authActions'`

The weird thing is, it only shows when using `build`, it works in development mode but not in production.

I've set up my aliases in package.json like [the docs](https://parceljs.org/module_resolution.html#aliases) say:

```
{
  "scripts: {
      "build-client": "parcel build client/index.html dist/client",
      "build-server": "parcel build server/index.js --target node -d dist/server",
      "build-test": "yarn build-server && node ./dist/server/index.js"
  },
  "alias": {
      "actions": "./client/actions"
  }
}
```

It's a server-side rendered app, I'm importing the component in different places and I can't use the default Parcel root, because it's relative to the entry file.

How can I get this to properly resolve aliases?

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked when parcel1 was the current version, so for anyone arriving here in the future, it's worth pointing out that Parcel 2 supports this through [glob aliases](https://parceljs.org/features/dependency-resolution/#glob-aliases)

Your `package.json` would include an entry like this:

```
{
  "alias": {
    "actions/*": "./client/actions/$1"
  }
}
```

Then, to import all the exports of `./client/actions/authActions`, you could write:

```
import * as authActions from "actions/authActions";
```

Comment: This just isn't working for me.  I have a very simple import... `import "middleware/async.js"`. And my alias (defined in the "alias" object from my package.json): `"middleware/*": "./src/middleware/$1"`